# Get item by Display name in sitecore

Tags: sitecore-query

How can I fetch the item by display name?

The below code is not working:

```
string url = string.Concat("fast:/sitecore/content/KeenanDirect/#" + string.Format(blogtype) + "#//*[@@Display name='",  displayname + "']");
sitecoreItem = database.Items.GetItem(url);
```

Comment: Can you try in this way: string url = string.Concat("fast:/sitecore/content/KeenanDirect/#" + string.Format(blogtype) + "#//*[@__Display name='",  displayname + "']");
                sitecoreItem = database.Items.GetItem(url); . Display name is a standafield and field  is "__DisplayName"

Comment: Can you give describe more. I didn't understood

Comment: I don't think it is a good idea to get the item by its display name and i would not recommend it

Answer (score 6):

First of all I do not recommend using FastQuery, because it can be really slow and many people have had problems with it: https://blog.coates.dk/2014/11/19/sitecore-fast-query-syntax-can-kill-your-sql-server-or-website/

But if you still want to use here is the trick:

The field in Sitecore is not Display Name, it is "**Display Name". 
All the `standard fields` are prefixed by "**" 2 underlines char.

[image: Image of Standard Field Definitions]

Your fast query should look like this:

```
fast:/sitecore/content//*[@#__Display Name#='homedisplayname']
```

The `Display Name` for my home item is: `homedisplayname`

I added #field name#  because multi word names should be encoded with "#"

I tried fast query in Developer Center and here are the results.

You need to change a bit of your code to have same pattern like my query from Developer Center.

[image: Results of Fast Query in Developer Center]

Comment: What you can suggest to use instead of FastQuery? What is the best practice for it?

Comment: Content search using solr search provider