# Sitecore API - Get item by display name

Tags: item-web-api

we are using sitecore as backend headless api (Not JSS). What i want to do is get the item by path - but the path will be display name.  i saw the question [here](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/8275/get-item-by-display-name-in-sitecore) to get item by display name - but that is only when the item itself has different name. How to do something similar if the entire path has different display name
for eg: if i have an item with path
`/en/website/home/folder1/folder2/parentItem/Item` 
and each one of it have a display name which corresponds to something like
`/en/website/mysite/products/men/jeans/levis-322`

How do i map the above to its actual item path. doing a for each loop in each item and getting its display name is not easy and performance oriented. Any suggestions if folks have tackled this before?

Comment: Is it possible to share some code snippet on what you have achieved up to now? Also what kind of API you are using, is it default Sitecore or custom one.

Comment: I assume you are using Sitecore Item Web API. This API does not support fetching items by display name unless you use the Sitecore Query trick as described in the link you've posted. You can fetch items by ID or you can implement redirects instead. Read more about item web api options in https://doc.sitecore.com/en/SdnArchive/upload/sdn5/modules/sitecore%20item%20web%20api/sitecore_item_web_api_developer_guide_sc66-71-a4.pdf.